# How to create own TypifiedElement

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, htmlelements

How to create own TypifiedElement for using it inside HtmlElement?

I created own CustomElement

```java
 public class YesNoRadio extends TypifiedElement {

     protected YesNoRadio(WebElement wrappedElement) {
        super(wrappedElement);
     }

 .... // some other methods here

 }
```

And tried to use it but got exception on my base page while init Elements

```java
 PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(driver), this);
```

My exception

```java
ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.exceptions.HtmlElementsException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such accessible constructor on object: com.mycompany.testing.htmlelements.company.element.YesNoRadio
        at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementFactory.createTypifiedElementInstance(HtmlElementFactory.java:51)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementDecorator.decorateTypifiedElement(HtmlElementDecorator.java:102)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementDecorator.decorate(HtmlElementDecorator.java:66)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:115)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:107)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementDecorator.decorateHtmlElement(HtmlElementDecorator.java:115)
        at ru.yandex.qatools.htmlelements.loader.decorator.HtmlElementDecorator.decorate(HtmlElementDecorator.java:70)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.proxyFields(PageFactory.java:115)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.initElements(PageFactory.java:107)
        at com.mycompany.testing.cds.PageBase.<init>(PageBase.java:46)
```

Where is my mistake and how to correct init my own TypifiedElement?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stacktrace, its likely the class from where you're creating the instance of `YesNoRadio` is in a different package. Therefore you need to declare the constructor of the latter as `public`

```
public YesNoRadio(WebElement wrappedElement) {
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's 100% correct - you should have public constructor in your elements.